# How to select everything after // and in the same line?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string this:

```
$str = 'this is a // comment
        I want to select this // comment';
```

Now I want to select everything which there is `//` behind it and in single line. And then put it between `<span class="comment-method">` and `</span>`. In this case I want this output:

```
$newstr = 'this is a <span class="comment-method"> comment </span>
           I want to select this <span class="comment-method"> comment </span>';
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Try something: Put your input into https://regex101.com and try something

Comment: @Rizier123 I did it. `/\/\/ [a-z]+/` here is my try :-) But it works just once

Comment: @stack the reason why he said to try something is because we're not just a code writing service. We're here to help so we want to see some effort from the asker :p. You might find better success from this: `\/\/.*` (also, turn on the global flag)

Comment: @stack https://regex101.com/r/hF0nD7/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/\/\/(.*)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/aU6rD4/2

This will capture everything after `//` and on the same line.

In php:

```
$str = 'this is a // comment
I want to select this // comment';
$newstr = preg_replace('/\/\/(.*)/', "<span class=\"comment-method\">$1</span>", $str);
```

https://3v4l.org/CC4fm

Comment: Just one thing, why have you used `.../g` ? In general when should I use `g` in the end of my regex?

Comment: @stack I put `g` there to signify that this regular expression match is to be performed globally. The way that you execute this global match is dependent on programmatic implementation. In the case of `preg_replace`, it will do the match globally by default for us.

Comment: @stack you can see this in the documentation under the `limit` parameter http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php *The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (**no limit**).*

Answer (score 0):

```
/\/\/\s*(.*)$/gm
```

`m` means treat `$` as end of line, not end of string.  `g` means global, find all matches

Comment: The `$` is pointless, isn't it? Additionally, the multiline flag is also pointless from my understanding.

Comment: @iismathwizard Agreed.

Comment: @stack From my understanding of your question you *"want to select everything which there is `//` behind it and in single line"* so wouldn't you want this instead? `/\/\/(.*)/g`

Comment: @ismathwizard without the multiline flag, `m`, the regex treats end-of-line like any other character.  With `m`, `$` is end-of-line aka newline, not end of the string and so captures just the comments on the line, `comment` and `comment`.  See this at https://regex101.com/r/wW8eK1/1 and see what happens when you remove the `m` flag (you only get 1 match because `.*` is greedy).

Comment: @BareNakedCoder what you fail to understand is that **you don't need the `$` and multiline flag**. `.` does **not** match the new line character. https://regex101.com/r/hF0nD7/2